# Python Keras: Pass y/target to custom activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to pass my **Python Keras** model `y` (target/response/etc) to a custom activation.

My custom activation function which limits the fit range to be within **lower** and **upper** is:

```
def activation_range(x, lower=-1, upper=1) :

    """
    Custom activation layer to restrict layer output range
    """

    x02 = backend.tanh(x) + 1 # x in range(0,2)
    scale = (upper-lower)/2
    return  x02 * scale + lower
```

and I have to pass it to Keras while initiating a follows

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=lambda x: activation_range(x, lower=lower, upper=upper)))
```

where upper and lower are calculated **before** the model.fit function is called.

However is there a way to set lower and upper based on the values of `y` e.g `lower = y.min()` and `upper = y.max()` **after the model has been initialised**, so Keras calculates upper and lower while fitting based on y (as model.fit is run), instead of me having to pass it to Keras **before**

Comment: Does it mean that your model must know about the target *before* making prediction about the target? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of predictions?

Comment: Not exactly. Ideally, y can be passed to the activation function as a parameter input, like x. Then with y, the upper and lower bounds can be dynamically set. The reason I want to pass y dynamically to the activation function, is so y can be set correctly when cross validating, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can. Just use *functional API* in combination with *subclassed layers* instead of the basic Sequential which only supports single-input single-output models. Note that this requires you to pass `(x,y)` as the `x` argument to `model.fit` and also as the input during inference.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class CustomActivation(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inp):
        x, y = inp
        upper = tf.math.reduce_max(y)
        lower = tf.math.reduce_min(y)
        return (tf.math.tanh(x) + 1) * (upper - lower) / 2 + lower

x_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,))
y_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
x_before_act = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation=None)(x_in)
x_after_act = CustomActivation()([x_before_act, y_in])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x_in, y_in], outputs=x_after_act)
```

You can verify this with the sample below and see that the model's output is always between -10 and 10.

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(32,10))
y = np.random.randint(low=-10, high=10, size=(32,))
model([x,y])
```

You can also compile and train the model as well.

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss=tf.keras.losses.mse)
model.fit(x=(x,y), y=y, epochs=1)
```

Comment: Hey @bui, I've tried what you said however after fitting the example you have above and then plotting the fit, the model has done a very poor job of fitting the data even after 200 epochs. Do you know how to improve the fit?

I used the following code to plot the fit:

fit = model.predict((x, y)).reshape(1, -1)[0]
plot_df = pd.DataFrame({'fit': fit, 'y': y}).sort_values('y').reset_index(drop=True).plot()

Comment: I used random input and output for my example just to demonstrate the solution to the question. No model can predict random output that is independent of input. If you applied the model to your own dataset and saw poor result, then it could be because of many other things. All I demonstrate in the answer is how to dynamically pass the clipping threshold (as per your question).

Comment: Yep that's fair enough. Thank you!